# HMAC-based one-time password, norm for how many counter events to check forwards in time (to see if user skipped a few)?

Tags: one-time-password

My bank seems to use something like HMAC-based one-time password, and it generates a new code every time I open it, and I could in theory skip a thousand codes (not use them to log in), and then the counter event value would have skipped forwards a thousand for the bank when they try to verify my hash.

I am interested for that reason in how many counter events banks (or applications that use similar types of one-time passwords) usually check. A thousand? Ten? A billion?

It's a very broad question, but I have nothing to go on, don't know how or where to find the documentation (could email my bank but they would likely have a hard time getting me in touch with whoever knows too), so I thought I'd ask here in case there is trends and norms around this.

Answer (score 2):

Most people nowadays use TOTP, which is the same as HOTP, but instead of a counter, it uses a timestamp.  Usually the timestamp is based on a 30-second counter, and typically there are three codes valid at any one time: the previous one, the current one, and the next one.

In such a case, if you give the user three tries to enter the right code, then that's roughly a $ 9 / 10^6 $ chance to guess the right code, which is about $ 1 / 10,000 $, assuming a 6-digit code.  As an additional security measure (a second factor, this is probably acceptable if there's rate-limiting and other security measures in place.  Some sites use an 8-digit code instead to improve security.

For an actual HOTP with a counter, I'm unclear as to what the standard is.  I would say 3 to 5 skipped codes would be reasonable, especially if you're using an 8-digit code.  Note that your bank may also use a system that separately uses your phone to contact a server and advise it of the counter, in which case, it can know exactly which value to accept and accept only the correct value.